# Getting and manipulating values from a table with checkboxes generated by an SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am new to programming and I found a working code which allows me to generate a table based from a query which also contains checkboxes in each row of the resulting table. How do I get/retrieve the values from the row/s which have been selected via the checkbox?

Here's the code which generates the table:

```
<?php

        function SQLResultTable($Query)
        {
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root" , "") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
            mysql_select_db("myDB") or die('Could not select database');        //select database
            $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

            $Table.= "<table border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\">"; //Open HTML Table

            $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
            if(mysql_error())
            {
                $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
            }
            else
            {
                //Header Row with Field Names
                $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
                $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\">";
                for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
                {
                    $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>";
                     if($i==$NumFields-1)
                     {
                     $Table.= "<th>&nbsp&nbspSelect&nbsp&nbsp</th>";
                     $Table.= "</tr>";
                     }
                }


                //Loop thru results
                $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
                while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
                {

                    //Alternate colors for rows
                    if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #FFCCCC;";
                    else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

                    $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
                    //Loop thru each field
                    foreach($Row as $field => $value)
                    {

                        $Table.= "<td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$value&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td>";

                    }
                    //$Table.= "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
                    $Table.= "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>";
                    $Table.= "</tr>";
                }

            }
            $Table.= "</table>";

            return $Table;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point would be to read the information on how to select information from a database.  With SQL generally this is done using `SELECT` statements.  The MySQL `SELECT` documentation can be found here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Using Google you should be able to find information regarding how to use a `SELECT` with MySQL and PHP.  Once you've had a go, and if you still can't figure out where you are going wrong, then post up a new question with specific information as to your problem and example code, and then I'm sure others will be able to provide you with advice relating to that specific problem.

**IMPORTANT**

As a security point of view, **NEVER** include usernames or passwords in your source code examples.  Just put in placeholder values instead.